# Android: boot loop kernel panic in meminfo_proc_show() 3.10.65+ trying to do a LOS12.1 port

Tags: android, linux-kernel, stack-trace, panic

I am trying to port the current ASB-patched LOS12.1 (github "cm12-amami") to a Teclast 98 (M1E9) tablet for which kernel sources are missing. My build completes fine, however, I run into a boot loop due to kernel panic with an (at least for me) totally unhelpful stack trace:

During init.rc processing, the kernel panics on logd startup when logd tries to read from /proc/meminfo with the following stack trace:

```
[  126.200788]00:02:29.656321 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/meminfo", O_RDONLY) = 4
[  126.200956]00:02:29.656496 fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
[  126.201077]00:02:29.656614 mprotect(0x7faf52b000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE) = 0
[  126.201187]00:02:29.656726 mprotect(0x7faf52b000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
[  126.202709]00:02:29.656833 read(4,
```

*** KERNEL PANIC HAPPENS HERE!!! ***

```
[  126.202739]<1> (1)[949:logd]<1>start....
[  126.202805]<1> (1)[949:logd]Unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at virtual address 00000016
[  126.202817]<1> (1)[949:logd]pgd = ffffffc070dee000

[  126.202828]<1> (1)[949:logd][00000016] *pgd=0000000000000000 (1)[949:logd]
[  126.202846]<1> (1)[949:logd][KERN Warning] ERROR/WARN forces debug_lock off!
[  126.202854]<1> (1)[949:logd][KERN Warning] check backtrace:
[  126.202868]<1> (1)[949:logd]CPU: 1 PID: 949 Comm: logd Tainted: G        W    3.10.65+ #1
[  126.202878]<1> (1)[949:logd]Call trace:
[  126.202899]<1> (1)[949:logd][<ffffffc000088f50>] dump_backtrace+0x0/0x16c
[  126.202913]<1> (1)[949:logd][<ffffffc0000890cc>] show_stack+0x10/0x1c
[  126.202931]<1> (1)[949:logd][<ffffffc0009a69a0>] dump_stack+0x1c/0x28
[  126.202947]<1> (1)[949:logd][<ffffffc0002f7210>] debug_locks_off+0x40/0x5c
[  126.202960]<1> (1)[949:logd][<ffffffc00009a260>] oops_enter+0xc/0x28
[  126.202974]<1> (1)[949:logd][<ffffffc000089100>] die+0x28/0x1d8
[  126.202989]<1> (1)[949:logd][<ffffffc0009a49ec>] __do_kernel_fault.part.5+0x70/0x84
[  126.203003]<1> (1)[949:logd][<ffffffc000094260>] do_page_fault+0x348/0x34c
[  126.203017]<1> (1)[949:logd][<ffffffc000094350>] do_translation_fault+0x40/0x4c
[  126.203030]<1> (1)[949:logd][<ffffffc0000813fc>] do_mem_abort+0x38/0x98
```

which does not seem to uncover the root cause, but rather the root cause stack trace seems to be:

```
[  133.341226]<1>-(1)[949:logd]Call trace:
[  133.341239]<1>-(1)[949:logd][<ffffffc0001f37d8>] meminfo_proc_show+0x50/0x3c4
[  133.341255]<1>-(1)[949:logd][<ffffffc0001aefb8>] seq_read+0x1a4/0x40c
[  133.341271]<1>-(1)[949:logd][<ffffffc0001ebeec>] proc_reg_read+0x4c/0x7c
[  133.341285]<1>-(1)[949:logd][<ffffffc00018e75c>] vfs_read+0x88/0x170
[  133.341298]<1>-(1)[949:logd][<ffffffc00018ebf0>] SyS_read+0x40/0x8c
[  133.341310]<1>-(1)[949:logd]Code: 52800001 91326000 97fe67c1 aa0003f3 (f9400c00) 
[  133.341322]<1>-(1)[949:logd]---[ end trace 1b75b31a2719ed20 ]---
[  133.341332]<1>-(1)[949:logd]Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal exception
[  133.341423]<1>-(1)[949:logd]mrdump: cpu[1] tsk:ffffffc073a3e000 ti:ffffffc070e64000
[  134.241428]<1>-(1)[949:logd]
```

Most interestingly, the exact same kernel blob can successfully boot stock Android 5.1 and successfully read from /proc/meminfo when booted from stock boot.img while it crashes with my LOS12.1 build boot.img.

bootimg.cfg (using abootimg) is identical in both cases (except the boot size):

```
bootsize = 0x780000
pagesize = 0x800
kerneladdr = 0x40080000
ramdiskaddr = 0x44000000
secondaddr = 0x40f00000
tagsaddr = 0x4e000000
name = 1513588375
cmdline = bootopt=64S3,32N2,64N2 androidboot.selinux=permissive
```

Thanks a million in advance for any ideas or pointers about what might be going wrong with this stock kernel blob and my LOS12.1 build with regards to meminfo_proc_show()!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally resolved by making changes (a whole number of, so I haven't tracked it down to one particular change) to my CM12.1 build's system partition, making it resemble the stock image more closely.

I still don't have any clues why the kernel would crash on reading from /proc/meminfo due to "wrong"/buggy contents in the system partition (/system file system), but as the issue is resolved, this can be regarded as a proof that such content in system can indeed matter in a critical way for the behaviour of the kernel...

My custom ROM for Teclast 98 (M1E9) runs fine now, I will publish a download link soon on xda.